# Retention policies: DevOps Artifacts vs JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, azure-artifacts

wanted to get the opinion of the people for this one. Currently I am working on setting retention policies inside Artifacts in DevOps, I want to get some clarification on how exactly that works. For example: Lets say I set my Max number of version per package to 10 and my Days to keep recently downloaded packages 14. I currently have these versions for my builds:
3.0.1.1.4
3.0.2.1.2 - 3.0.2.1.8
3.1.2.0.1 - 3.1.2.0.4
Is it possible with azure retention policies to keep versions 3.0.1, even if its not the latest version of my build? I assume it will just save the 10 latest versions of the build which would be 3.0.2.1.2 - 3.1.2.0.4. Let me know if I am assuming correctly. Assume no packages have been downloaded for this scenario.

Another alternative I was thinking about using is maybe Artifactory, who to me seems fairly similar? Not really too sure about it. I want to know which one is best for retention policies overall to reduce cost. Any information help, I know its not the clear thing in the world so if you have any questions just let me know.

Comment: Maybe that helps : On Azure DevOps package are deleted by retention policy if both criteria are met : number of packages > 10 AND package not downloaded since 14 days in your case. cf. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8697

Comment: I don't understand your build versions: how many digits is your build version made of ?